# Render movie to a OpenGL texture in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

Is it possible to render a movie to an OpenGL texture in real time using the Apple iOS frameworks?
I've seen it in an [old NeHe tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/playing_avi_files_in_opengl/23001/) using glTexSubImage2D, but I'm wondering how can I access the RGB data using the Apple frameworks?

init

```
NSString *mPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:mPath];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:options];

imgGen = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
imgGen.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
imgGen.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
```

each frame

```
double time = 0.xyz * asset.duration;

CMTime reqTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds (time, preferredTimeScale), actTime;
NSError *err = nil;
CGImageRef ref = [imgGen actualTime:&actTime error:&err];

//... GL calls to make an image from the CGImageRef
```

This method is incredibly slow for realtime rendering, and I can only generate ~15 frames.  One way may be to generate frames on the fly asynchronsly, but surely it can be done in real time?  The most time consuming part is the copyCGImageAtTime call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS4: how do I use video file as an OpenGL texture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621627/ios4-how-do-i-use-video-file-as-an-opengl-texture)

Comment: Check out Tommy's answer to the above question, because that should do what you want here.  The image generator is intended to be used for thumbnails, so I don't think it will ever give you the realtime performance you need.