# IOS4: video texture in OpenGL ES

Tags: video, opengl-es, ios4, textures

I am new to OpenGL ES 2 but I am still required to finish a project pretty quickly.  I want to add a video to be an object's texture in openGL on ios4.

Although I know that the answer was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621627/ios4-how-do-i-use-video-file-as-an-opengl-texture), I am having trouble putting the pieces together on how to go about doing that.

It will be very appreciated if someone can post how to do that in a code snippet or point on me how to start.